# How to access data from Method in Computed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Methods:

```
methods: {
    fetchData () {
      axios.get(globalConfig.ORDERS_URL, {
        params: {
          limit: this.limit,
          offset: this.offset
        }
      })
        .then((resp) => {
          this.req = resp.data
          console.log(resp)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Computed:

```
  computed: {
    filteredRequests () {
      return this.req.results.filter(item => {
        return item.created.toLowerCase().includes(this.name)
      })
    }
  }
```

Data:

```
  data () {
    return {
      req: {},
    }
  }
```

Parsing data from API endpoint, but i can't use `req` object in a computed method at all, it throws an error.

Contents of `req` object:

[image]

I also have used:

```
  created () {
    this.fetchData()
  },

  watch: {
    '$route': 'fetchData'
  }
```

So, when i use `req` object in a template directly - it works, but i cannot call it in a computed method to filter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `this.req.results` in `computed` while the initial data is `req: {}` and asynchronous `fetchData()` method does not resolve instantly, that's why it causes an error. Do something like:

```
computed: {
  filteredRequests () {
    if (this.req.results) {
      return this.req.results.filter(item => {
        return item.created.toLowerCase().includes(this.name)
      })
    } else {
      return 'No results'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a typo, answer has been updated, please try again.

Comment: Thanks, it does work now. Also could you advice on how to make my filter ignore case sensitive values? `return item.created.toLowerCase().includes(this.name)`

Comment: Is `item.created` a string which must contain a `name` string?

Comment: Yes, but if i type in a higher case it won't find a result. Only in lower-case it works for now.

Comment: I think name must be lowercased too: `return item.created.toLowerCase().includes(this.name.toLowerCase())`